# Determing whether or not the range of a linear transformation is linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $W$ be a vector space and let $T: W \to W$.  Suppose that $n,m$ are positive integers.

(True or False) If there exists a $w\in W$ such that $T^nw\neq0$ and $T^{n+1}w=0$, then $\{w,Tw,...,T^nw\}$ is linearly independent.

(True or False)  Let $V$ be the subspace formed by the span of the vectors in the previous question.  If there exists a $v \in W$ such that $T^mv\notin V$ and $T^{m+1}v \in V$, then $\{w,Tw,...,T^nw,v,Tv,...,T^mv\}$
 is linearly independent.

I was hoping for some hints on how to get started.  I've been thinking that the first question is an application of Cayley-Hamilton.  But I'm not sure how to start the second one at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both statements are true. Assume $$0 = \alpha_0w + \alpha_1 Tw + \alpha_2T^2w\cdots + \alpha_n T^nw$$

and apply $T^{n}$ to both sides of the equality. We get $$0 = \alpha_0T^n w + \alpha_1 \underbrace{T^{n+1}w}_{= 0} + \alpha_n \underbrace{T^{2n}w}_{= 0} = \alpha_0\underbrace{T^n w}_{\ne 0}$$
 We conclude $\alpha_0 = 0$ and proceed inductively:

Assume that $\alpha_0 = \cdots = \alpha_{k-1} = 0$ and let's show that $\alpha_{k} = 0$.

We have

$$0 = \alpha_kT^{k}w + \cdots + \alpha_nT^{n}w$$

Applying $T^{n-k}$ we obtain

$$0 = \alpha_kT^nw + \alpha_{k+1}\underbrace{T^{n+1}w}_{=0} + \cdots + \alpha_n\underbrace{T^{2n-k}w}_{=0} = \alpha_k\underbrace{T^nw}_{\ne 0}$$

and thus $\alpha_k = 0$. Hence we conclude $\alpha_0 = \cdots = \alpha_n = 0$ so the set $\{w, Tw, \ldots, T^nw\}$ is linearly independent.

---

For the second stament,  assume

$$0 = \alpha_0w + \alpha_1 Tw + \alpha_2T^2w\cdots + \alpha_n T^nw + +\beta_0v + \beta_1 Tv + \beta_2 T^2v + \cdots + \beta_m T^mv$$

and apply $T^{m}$ to both sides of the equality. Because $\{w, Tw, \ldots, T^nw\}$ is $T$-invariant, we get

$$0 = (\text{something in $V$}) + \beta_0 \underbrace{T^{m}v}_{\notin V} $$

Since $T^{m}v \notin V$ we conclude $\beta_0 = 0$ and proceed inductively:

Assume $\beta_0 = \cdots = \beta_{k-1} = 0$ so we have

$$0 = \alpha_0w + \alpha_1 Tw + \alpha_2T^2w\cdots + \alpha_n T^nw + \beta_kT^kv + \cdots + \beta_m T^mv$$

Applying $T^{m-k}$ we obtain

$$0 = (\text{something in $V$}) + \beta_k \underbrace{T^{m}v}_{\notin V} $$

Since $T^{m}v \notin V$ we conclude $\beta_k = 0$. Therefore $\beta_0 = \cdots = \beta_m = 0$.

Now we have

$$0 = \alpha_0w + \alpha_1 Tw + \alpha_2T^2w\cdots + \alpha_n T^nw$$

and by the linear independence of $\{w, Tw, \ldots, T^nw\}$ we finally conclude $\alpha_0 = \cdots = \alpha_n = 0$ so all scalars are $0$.

Hence, $\{w, Tw, \ldots, T^nw, v, Tv, \ldots, T^mv\}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: Do you mean apply $T^{n+1}$.

Comment: @Annalena No, you want only the first term to remain.

Comment: I guess I don't understand where we will end up using $T^{n+1}$ assumption.

Comment: Also, is it just repeated application of $T^{n-1}$?

Comment: @Annalena When you apply $T^{n-1}$ you get
$$0 = T^{n-1}(\alpha_1 Tw + \alpha_2T^2w\cdots + \alpha_n T^nw) = \alpha_1 \underbrace{T^nw}_{\ne 0} + \underbrace{\alpha_2 T^{n+1}w}_{=0} + \cdots + \underbrace{\alpha_2 T^{2n-1}w}_{=0}$$
The assumption $T^{n+1}w = 0$ is used to cancel every term other than the first. When you conclude that $\alpha_1 = 0$ then apply $T^{n-2}$, then $T^{n-3}$ and so on.

Comment: Ah, so I show it for $\alpha_1$.  Suppose this holds for all $n-1$.  Then I'm left with $T^n\alpha_n$.  But $T^n$ is already non-zero.  So this is linearly independent.

Comment: @Annalena Exactly. Or rather, supposing $\alpha_1 = \ldots = \alpha_{k-1} = 0$, you have
$$0 = \alpha_kT^{k}w + \cdots + \alpha_nT^{n}w$$
Now apply $T^{n-k}$ to this and you get $0 = \alpha_k\underbrace{T^nv}_{\ne 0}$. Hence $\alpha_k = 0$.

Comment: I see.  Since I assumed it holds for $k-1$ nd that it held for $k$, would I be done?

Comment: @Annalena Yes, if you assume that it holds for $k-1$ and prove that it holds for $k$, you're done.

Comment: Does it matter that the lone $w$ doesn't appear to be accounted for?

Comment: I noticed that in both cases you appear to be ignoring the $w$ and $v$ which are hit by $T^0$.

Comment: I hate that I keep noticing these after the fact, but $T^{m+1}\in V$.  I believe the second one is wrong.

Comment: @Annalena Indeed, I forgot about $v$ and $w$, and I misread the second statement. I have edited the answer and added more details. Do you agree with it now?